# Simple apache mina http server with basic authorization

Tags: java, basic-authentication, apache-mina, httpserver

I know about asyncweb, but documentation for 2.0 version doesn't exists(or may be Internet ban me today).

So, if someone had same experience with Apache Mina and Http server with Basic authentication, please, tell me.

Thanks.